Where zoom? How to purge it?
I have here Zoom package installed, I see on my interface and can used it... But it is not at

apt list --installed | grep -i zoom
grep -i zoom /var/lib/apt/extended_states
dpkg -l | grep -i zoom

... Why UBUNTU has no unified list of packages?

Have a look at the /opt directory. Maybe that helps you.

Installed as a snap? Run snap list to check if zoom-client is installed.

"Why UBUNTU has no unified list of packages?"  Because debian does not have one ;-)  Now you asked it ... I would assume it would not be too difficult to make a script to list all packages. all snaps, all flatpacks, and find all the executables in /opt/. There must be a catch somewhere :-P
